# Color splash transition (inline-diff) as a highlight after retrieving edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, diff

I know that clicking on the **Edited N minutes ago** button after an edit to a post works perfectly like this:
[image: Side-by-side Markdown Diff]

I want to suggest a feature that would help a lot once implemented.

### The Feature

After retrieving the community edits, a green-colored splash should occur (highlighting) to the newly added texts (similar to that `inline diff`) to the question that automatically comes to the usual color after N (ideally, 1-3) seconds, like transitioning. The visitors who are on the same page will easily catch those edits instantly instead of questioning - *oh, what's just changed?* and reading again (if we don't want to see question history time and again).

In the case of the deleted content, a red inline diff splash should occur, and as soon as the animation ends, all of the deleted text should go invisible.

**Note:** I'm talking about the questions page and the change when the updated/edited post is displayed.

---

### Expected Advantages

1. Less time consumption to answer a question when an edit takes place.
2. No need to see question history if the user was on the same page when the question was edited.
3. This is expected to be helpful for long-text questions.

Comment: Yeah, I've often been on a page when a post gets edited right after I finish reading it and I immediately think "wait, what changed?" when nothing different stands out. This would probably be easy enough to implement client-side on your own if one cared to.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think exactly as you do! – and then I need to go to the history and read that and making changes to the answer after this makes a bit time consuming.

Comment: How do you add a color splash to deleted text?

Comment: @CrisLuengo the text should remain until the red-colored animation ends and as soon as it ends, the deleted text after obtaining the edit will be deleted simply. **It's just my theory.**

Comment: I really don't understand what you are proposing here. Are you saying that a post's background should flash green when a suggested edit is pending? This would be in addition to the "edit" link changing to "edit (1)"? Do you feel that that indicator is not obvious enough?

Comment: @CodyGray No, the green splash must occur only to the newly added texts in the edited post.

Comment: So... you want inline diffs? That seems confusing. How am I supposed to do a side-by-side comparison when it only stays visible for a few seconds (as a "splash")? And what about deleted content?

Comment: @CodyGray *what about deleted content* – that I already mentioned in the previous comment, mentioning Cris above.

Comment: People who really care for what changes can easily go to the history page. Most of the time, this feature is not needed and even when it needed there are already way to achieve the goals without the feature.

Comment: @RohanBari as currently written your feature request is quite confusing, it is seemingly suggesting to add a color splash on the revision page (your image might have made me think in that direction), you should specify that you are talking about the questions page itself and the change when the updated / edited post is displayed.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat amended.